# Bootstrap confirm modal bihaind main modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have image gallery with comments. That image is opened in modal.
When i try to remove image comment i open new confirm modal. Problem is becouse that confirm modal goes bihaind the main modal. Check screenshot

Number 1 is main modal. on click `x` inside on comment i open number 2 modal but he is bihaind.

[image]

I try to put that delete modal first with `z-index` but not work

```
#confirm-delete {
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

Comment: can u create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Don't manually set a modal's z-index! I personally use this: http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/ It made Bootstrap modals so much better with little configuration. And it is stackable, it might just solves your problem.

Comment: Yea stackable slove my problem. Thanks @DanielCheung

Comment: @Zend, you're welcome! I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never manually set a modal's z-index!

The problem occurred because Bootstrap doesn't order the modals' z-index by default.

I personally use this: http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal It made Bootstrap modals so much better with little configuration. And it is stackable, it might just be the best way to solve your problem.

I'm assuming you are using Bootstrap 3, the following code will do well.

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Load the CSS resources in this order, the plugin will automatically manage the z-index of modals.